# Unvested "RSE" on W-2 Box 14

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-2, amended-tax-return, rsu

My spouse's employer has granted him  RSUs (which for some reason they call RSE) as part of a long term incentive plan. It is a set amount granted ever year over the past 3 years, but none of it has vested yet (4 year schedule per grant). However, they include this grant in the Box 14 of his W-2 every year as "$XX,XXX.XX RSE"

I did not know until recently that none of these funds have vested yet, so I was adding this on TurboTax Box 14 of his W-2, which caused us to pay substantially more taxes than expected. Can I safely assume that I do not need to add this "RSE" fund on Box 14 this year, and maybe even file amended returns for the past two years? When the RSUs start vesting this year, will they appear under a different category in his 2022 W-2?

Comment: `which caused us to pay substantially more taxes than expected` - why? How did it show up in your forms? What changed on your 1040 when you removed it?